# powershell variable not printing value as expected

Tags: powershell

```
$FShares = "\\server\share"

ForEach ($f in $FShares)

{

    $Access = Get-Acl $f | select-object -ExpandProperty Access | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "XXXXXXXXX*"} 
    Write-Output "------- Share ------------------------------"
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output $f
    Write-Output ""
    ForEach ($a in $Access)
    {
        Write-Output "------- Groups, Permission and Users -------"
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output $a
        Write-Output ""
        $strGroup = $a.IdentityReference.ToString()
        $Members = $strGroup.split('\')[1] | foreach {Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_} | select-object Name
        Write-Output $Members
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output ""
    }
}
```

When I run this script, the line (Write-Output $Members) does not print to screen. After I run the script I can run it manually (either doing a write-output or just the variable name) and it prints fine so I know that the variable has a value. not sure what's wrong here

Comment: All the other lines are printed properly to screen?

Comment: Most likely would be that none of the IdentityReference values matched "XXXXXXXXX*", try outputting `$strGroup` to check you still have a value there. BTW your `Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights` does nothing useful: it simply removes attributes that you are going to ignore anyway.

Comment: @Duncan it does do something useful - the objects are printed by `Write-Output "$a"` so if you don't select the properties you care about, it writes all the properties.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler right, I missed that. Mixing strings and objects in the output pipeline sounds a bit of a risky business though.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 Write-Output $a
```

to

```
 Write-Output "$a"
```

Edit, better:

```
 Write-Output $a | ft
```

I'd like to expand on why that's breaking it, but I have no idea.